# Shipping Charge Using Define Function (Python)

Tags: python

I'm trying to program this assignment using the define function. Here is what I've done so far. Please let me know if I can do anything. There is an error to my code and I'm having difficulty debugging it. Perhaps I'm not using the define function right? Thank you for your time.

Write a function to calculate a Shipping Charge. The parameters will be the number of books, the flat charge (which should default to $3.00), and the charge per book (which should default to $1.99). For example, in the default case, 2 books would be charged $3 plus $3.98 (1.99 per book) for a total of $6.98.

For the Demo, order 3 books. Let the flat rate be waived (i.e. $0.00), and the default per-book rate apply.

```
import math


def me():
N = int(input("How Many Books?="))
Shipping=(1.99*N)+3
print(format(Shipping,',d'))
me()
```

I also have an error when I put the code in....

```
import math 
def me(): 
N = int(input("How Many Books?=")) 
Shipping=(1.99*N)+3 
print(format(Shipping,'0.2f')) 
me()
```

File "", line 3
    N = int(input("How Many Books?="))
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
Unknown error.

Comment: You need to ask a question, do you think something is wrong with your code or are you getting error's?

Comment: I edited my post. I'm getting an error and it's not telling me what's wrong with it.

Comment: Try: `print(format(Shipping,'0.2f'))`

Comment: @John1024, I'm getting an error. Would I have to delete anything? How do I incorporate flat rate? Do you think Shipping=(1.99*N)+3 is a good code to work?

Comment: @python2learn The statement that I gave you was to __replace__ the existing `print` statement.  So, yes, the old `print` statement would need to be deleted.  Also, for best results on stackoverflow, please quote error messages exactly and in full.  Since python error messages in particular are multiline, it is best to place them in the body of your question rather than in a comment.

Comment: @John1024. Thank you for your input. And understood about the heads up. I'm new here but I will utilize it well. I don't know if this is a common problem but I'm having an error with the third line... N  = int(input("How Many Books?=")) It's saying that N is not defined, am I missing a line? I thought N is already defined, or should I replace me with N?

Comment: @python2learn That does not sound right.  Can you quote the complete error message exactly?  Just copy and paste it into your question.

Comment: @John1024. Sure this is what I get when I put the code..   import math 
.. def me(): 
.. N = int(input("How Many Books?=")) 
.. Shipping=(1.99*N)+3 
.. print(format(Shipping,'0.2f')) 
.. me()
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    N = int(input("How Many Books?="))
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
Unknown error.

Comment: @John1024. I put the error question in my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In python, blocks of code are defined by indentation.  Other languages often use braces to group statements.  Python uses indentation.

In your case, you are defining a function called `me`.  The statements belonging to that function need to be indented as follows:

```
import math
def me():
    N = int(input("How Many Books?="))
    Shipping=(1.99*N)+3
    print(format(Shipping,'0.2f'))
me()
```

Note that the three statements that form the body of function `me` are equally indented from the `def` statement.

A run with the above code looks like:

```
$ python me.py 
How Many Books?=3
8.97
```

Comment: Uunderstood. The code runs perfectly now. Thank you so much for your help.